# How to query newly added data from parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, data-synchronization

I am using parse.com as a database for my app.
My app is like a social network.
i have a post table in parse
I want to query  post from parse and added to my recyclerview
if the the latest post from post table is not the same with the latest post in my local recycleview. How can i check this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for queries. I'm not familiar with Android/Java, but queries have lessThan / greaterThan methods. You can do a query whereKey:"createdAt" greaterThan:topPostInRecycleView.createdAt, or something along those lines. I'm not sure what the syntax will be. Here's the link to the API.

https://parse.com/docs/android/api/

Go there and ctrl + f greaterthan